# What would I use to fill a hole in a brick, so that I can re-drill a new hole that overlaps it?

Tags: outdoor, brick, hose

I'm replacing a sillcock in the backyard, which is mounted onto brick, and unfortunately the holes to anchor it are just slightly off and overlap.

I'd need to fill the old hole with something that can be re-drilled for the new anchors.

Would I use an epoxy, or some kind of mortar?

Experience appreciated.

Thanks!

EDIT: adding image to depict the situation
[image]

Comment: “Slightly” as in 1/2” or 1/8” ? Drill out ans glue a wood plug in then secure. Or mount it slightly higher or lower.

Comment: Yes that would be good to know since there are anchors out there that will allow tolerance up to 1/4" if not 1/2 if treated properly

Comment: Thanks for the help guys.  I've added a picture to the question to depict what I'm up against.  The metal mounting plate around the sillcock puts the mounting holes in different places.